# VB.NET code dumper

Tags: vb.net

Hello im a beginner and i need to make a tool that will dump some codes that i need from a text file.

This is how the text file looks

> 79nxO´.[„Ò€D JƒÚY S 4   A4B67368-30F84CD6-930CEA07-C2645CDC
>   lÁ°uµ¥?_2¶›]éÚ[™tiipDAe LƒÚX S 4
>   1E2F44FA-19F77EC4-8212CEBF-6A196C36   é9£ð÷åÂ“™—3-šÍïiÃä{r&GŠ JƒÚW
>   S 4   65735EC4-415C4232-91691832-8A8BE21F!VoS
>   Z˜©giàë½ÓX³ÁUhÛÇÖò LƒÚV S 4
>   CD3B3376-4638422A-A171BB50-00D194CC   Û¾A@X "|ÂÒ9þ-¶=M¬°E¾+ JƒÚU
>   S 4
>   00D1996F-7F834C0F-A7B7F798-7CA393DE!¥£à«auA¾¼¢˜•ÈÖk}®˜¤ JƒÚT
>   S 4   8656E931-79CC8FFE-B11B168F-FEB84D92 ?Ø`7pñBŽj¦Ù\
>   üXáæƒÕfø JƒÚS S 4   B72C3724-880944E8-B3B4CC58-EB7EB7E7 -
>   0íi/è+›N -‘”rU’[p$ JƒÚR S 4
>
>   CD9A4A87-1119464B-934C46AE-A36CF157 *µË0´eb€Ò;D Y6µ»Õ£”ê JƒÚQ
>   S 4   BC7F993F-A87F450F-A1BCC1E6-1FC9518D
>   (>þÐ¬0®žðR®ZV[óL¨¨lŒ;ôm¤ LƒÚP S 4
>
>   A3F8CC05-BABB4DB6-97E47D7E-7428D2CA   ÜÌ ðs4¸ÌÏF¦Xf=êmHšÍÄô JƒÚO
>   S 4   C0A2FEE7-C0264D80-A1F8705A-EEA24595`
>   #` IÐ]dÒ"ÎÑfþ0Äõ-®"€<³= JƒÚN S 4
>   E4D327F0-DE664C4E-BA1644BF-F0E5221C  ¿Ptô(F3Ù™°Ú¹•žÒQÁü* JƒÚM
>   S 4   9671B975-D90D4854-9F3FAE97-A8F24DD2
>   ª°®õËÛH?y[ÛvN;ÿC‹[ JƒÚL S 4
>   82A717AB-8A0546EE-916657E9-FA87BD44 ={ÃPHÕÔŽš„ôÐ³Òmâ ße5½j&u JƒÚK
>   S 4   9BD782BF-8E684DDC-B987FD8F-EF10871F
>   :—w°ALR-•ÿ•àz/N.ýœv˜arÚ LƒÚJ S 4
>   AC87845A-B7B64B22-A293D713-C46739F0   Ô¥60‘8Ä|I'Ýc¿!\¨ÃlçÒ JƒÚI

And this is for example a code "A4B67368-30F84CD6-930CEA07-C2645CDC"
I need to grab those out the file.

Comment: That's great! What's your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This looks like a regular expression might be an approach that would work.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I put OP's text in a text file and wrote some VB.NET code to find question marks. There were three! :^)

Comment: If i should use io.streamreader and how to sort them out. by finding a "-" first? and then 8 chars back. thats where im lost

Comment: why dont you try that and get back to us when you have a specific problem

Comment: Looks like the OP somehow messed up the question, I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily parse the targeted codes using a Regular Expression:

```
' copy & paste your string here, be sure to escape quotes properly
Dim s As String = "INSERT YOUR STRING HERE"

Dim rx As Regex
Dim m As MatchCollection

' This Regular Expression looks for a pattern like xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
' where the x's are A thru F or Zero thru Nine
rx = New Regex("([A-F0-9]{8}\-[A-F0-9]{8}\-[A-F0-9]{8}\-[A-F0-9]{8})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
m = rx.Matches(s)
For Each item In m
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(item.ToString)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand, but looks like it's groups of 8 characters separated by hyphens you seek?

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example
   Public Sub Main()
      Dim input As String = "the input you have above"
      Dim pattern As String = "[A-Za-z0-9]{8}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{8}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{8}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{8}" 
      Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
      Do While m.Success 
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1}", m.Value, m.Index)
         m = m.NextMatch()
      Loop                       
   End Sub 
End Module
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx

Comment: Yes Jimmy thats right thanks for the help